# Запись проигрываемого аудиопотока

Tags: android, android-audio-record

Есть ссылка на онлайн радио http://variant.fm:8000/LOVE-32. В приложении реализовано проигрывание этого аудио потока с помощью `exoplayer`. Нажимаю плей - запускается проигрывание, а при нажатии на стоп - останавливается. С этим все хорошо.

Хочу сделать еще две кнопки "Запись" и "Остановка". При нажатии на запись должна начаться запись в файл этого потока, а при нажатии на остановку запись заканчивается.

Например, идет проигрывание потока и нажали запись: создался файл mp3 на телефоне в какой-то папке, и, пока не нажали остановка, в этот файл записывается поток, а когда нажмут остановка, запись останавливается, и мы имеем итоговый mp3 файл.

Как реализовать такое? Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие статьи почитать, какие примеры посмотреть? Во многих приложениях онлайн радио в плеймаркете реализовано такое, и хочу такой же функционал реализовать в своем приложении.

Comment: Никто не поможет?

Answer (score 1):

В [документации плеера](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html) я не нашел возможности обрабатывать входящий поток, возможно стоит попробовать другие плееры перед тем, как делать свою реализацию записи. Для работы с аудио потоками Вам понадобится [android-ffmpeg](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg), для работы с мп3 структурой [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic).

Comment: Я знаю что нужно побайтово сохранить но не знаю как реализовать. Мне кажется что не нужно задумываться о том что происходит на сервере.

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна Вам нужно разобраться сначало с форматом мп3,  взять байтовый поток и добавить структуру мп3 файла на клиентской стороне скорее всего будет сложнее, чем реализовать на серверной

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна например, если Вам очень уж хочется реализовать это на клиентской стороне, тогда первая ссылка из гугла ведет на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501286/how-to-convert-an-audiobuffer-to-a-mp3-file

Comment: Я не понимаю почему вы пишите про клиентскую и серверную сторону. Есть множество приложений "Онлайн радио", где реализована возможность записи проигрываемой песни. Я попробовала декомпилировать несколько приложений таких и не увидела что там клиентскую какую-то реализацию или серверную. В одном проекте идет есть побайтовое сохранение, но код там получится кривой и сложно очень разобраться в этом коде.

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна потому что исходя из Вашего вопроса  было не понятно, разрабатываете Вы сайт и приложение либо только приложение. Теперь все прояснилось. Вам понадобится 2 библиотеки - https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg для работы со стримом аудио и вторая https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic для простановки и редактирования мп3 тегов, потому что стрим с радио или других интернет источников в 90% случаев идет без дополнительной мета информации

Answer (score 0):

Exoplayer, [как говорят разработчики](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1167), не поддерживает запись аудиопотока, лучшим решением будет найти другую библиотеку.

Comment: Есть предложения по поводу других библиотек?